# Change desktop background

Tags: c#, .net, image, console

I've created a simple program that downloads an image (different image every day), then sets it as my desktop background.

It is a console application, and closes immediately after downloading the image and setting it as my desktop background. It runs every morning at 6:00 AM via Task Scheduler.

Although I have significantly improved my program structure, I want to know if there are any poor practices currently in my code, or improvements that can be made.

[Link to the original program:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60755/set-desktop-background)

The updated, final version is formatted below.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Background
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            String URL = getBackgroundURL();
            Image background = downloadBackground(URL + getResolutionExtension());
            saveBackground(background);
            setBackground(background, PicturePosition.Fill);
        }

        public static String getBackgroundURL()
        {
            using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading JSON...");
                    String jsonString = webClient.DownloadString("super secret URL");
                    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
                    String backgroundURL = "image_url.com" + jsonObject.images[0].urlbase;
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded JSON!\n");    
                    return backgroundURL;
            }
        }

        public static Boolean websiteExists(String URL)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                return(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch {return false;}
        }

        public static String getResolutionExtension()
        {
            Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            String potentialURL = "_" + resolution.Width + "x" + resolution.Height + ".jpg";
            if(websiteExists(potentialURL)) return potentialURL;
            else return "_1920x1080.jpg";
        }

        public static Image downloadBackground(String URL)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading background...");
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
                HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse =(HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
                Image background = Image.FromStream(stream);
                Console.WriteLine("Downloaded background!\n");
                return background;
        }

        public static String getBackgroundPath()
        {
            String directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) + "/Backgrounds/";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            return Path.Combine(directory, DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy")+".bmp");
        }

        public static Boolean saveBackground(Image background)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Saving background...");
                background.Save(getBackgroundPath(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                Console.WriteLine("Saved background!\n");
                return true;
            }
            catch {return false;}
        }

        public enum PicturePosition
        {
            Tile, Center, Stretch, Fit, Fill
        }

        internal sealed class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            internal static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
                int uAction, 
                int uParam, 
                String lpvParam, 
                int fuWinIni);
        }

        public static void setBackground(Image background, PicturePosition style)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting background...");
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
            switch(style)
            {
            case PicturePosition.Tile:
                key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "0");
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1");
                break;
            case PicturePosition.Center:
                key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "0");
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0");
                break;
            case PicturePosition.Stretch:
                key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "2");
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0");
                break;
            case PicturePosition.Fit:
                key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "6");
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0");
                break;
            case PicturePosition.Fill:
                key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "10");
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0");
                break;
            }
            key.Close();

            const int SET_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND = 20;
            const int UPDATE_INI_FILE = 1;
            const int SEND_WINDOWS_INI_CHANGE = 2;
            NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SET_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND, 0, getBackgroundPath(), UPDATE_INI_FILE | SEND_WINDOWS_INI_CHANGE);
            Console.WriteLine("Set background!\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These `using` directives are not needed and can be safely removed:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Method names should be `PascalCase`:

- `getBackgroundURL` => `GetImageUrl`
- `websiteExists` => `WebsiteExists`
- `getResolutionExtension` => `GetResolutionExtension`
- `downloadBackground` => `DownloadImage`
- `getBackgroundPath` => `GetImageFilePath`
- `saveBackground` => `SaveBackground` - this would be more precise as `SaveImageFile`
- `setBackground` => `SetBackground` - this would be more precise as `SetDesktopWallpaper`

`URL` as part of a member name, should be `Url`; as a parameter name, should be `url`.

I would move the nested types `PicturePosition` and `NativeMethods` to another file, named after the type (respectively, `PicturePosition.cs` and `NativeMethods.cs`).

In this snippet:

> ```
> RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
> switch (style)
> {
>     case PicturePosition.Tile:
>         key.SetValue(@"PicturePosition", "0");
>         key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1");
>         break;
> ```

There's a possibility for a `NullReferenceException` on every access of the `key` object, including `key.Close()` - also, since .net 4.0 the `RegistryKey` implements `IDisposable`, which means it should be wrapped with a `using` block and not closed explicitly:

```
try
{
    using(var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true))
    {
        switch (style)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Specified registry key was not found.");
}
```

I'm not a big fan of that `switch` block, but abstracting a concept here would probably be overkill.

The verbatim specifier on `@"PicturePosition"` and `@"TileWallpaper"` isn't needed, as there are no escapes/backslashes in these strings.

I like that your type declarations are *consistently* explicit, but I would personally prefer them *consistently* implicit (i.e. using `var`) - but the keyword here is only "consistently", so that's just my own personal preference here.

This notation makes it hard to, say, add attributes to your enums, or just to maintain them in general:

> ```
> public enum PicturePosition
> {
>     Tile, Center, Stretch, Fit, Fill
> }
> ```

Enum members should be laid out vertically:

```
public enum PicturePosition
{
    Tile,
    Center,
    Stretch,
    Fit,
    Fill
}
```

---

This is a nice missed opportunity for `string.Concat`:

> ```
> String potentialURL = "_" + resolution.Width + "x" + resolution.Height + ".jpg";
> ```

Overall I like your methods, they're small and relatively specialized, and are generally well named. I'd consider regrouping them into similar-themed classes:

- `WebClient` and `JsonConvert`-related stuff into one.
- IO-related stuff into another.

This would only leave `Main` and `SetBackground` in the `Program` class, resulting in 3 smaller, specialized classes.

Comment: @Josque in regards to the unused `using` statements: If you right-click and select "Organize Usings", there is an option to remove these automagically.

Comment: I have 2 questions. Firstly, is there any benefit to implicitly declaring variables? Secondly, is there any benefit to using `String.Concat()` compared to regular operator concatenation? Otherwise great review.

Comment: I find implicit declarations with `var` make C# code read more fluently; instead of `SomeType foo = new SomeType()` you get `var foo = new SomeType()`. Strings are immutable in .net; using `String.Concat` avoids generating useless objects. Thanks for the checkmark! :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [@Mathieu Guidon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mathieu-guindon) wrote, to make **re-use** (copying code to other projects) easier, instead of referencing

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

I would **fully qualify** calls to those, i.e.

> RegistryKey key = **Microsoft.Win32**.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
>
> dynamic jsonObject = **Newtonsoft.Json**.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

and all other occurances like that (if they are candidates for re-use, of course). After you have done that, right click in the editor and select **"Remove and sort usings"** (or use the chord <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). This will keep only the remaining required usings.

And I would take advantage of **XML comments** (just type above your method `///` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>) to self-document the methods you're writing, i.e.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets background image of current user's desktop
/// </summary>
/// <param name="backgroundFilePath">Path to picture file (*.bmp or *.jpg)</param>
/// <param name="style">One of enum PicturePosition</param>
/// <remarks>optionally put some remarks here</remarks>
public static void SetBackground(string backgroundFilePath, PicturePosition style)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting background...");
    // ... code as you provided ..
}
```

This allows you to fully take advantage of Microsoft's **Intellisense**, i.e. just point on the name of the method and get its description and parameters (more about it [is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507335/what-is-the-purpose-of-remarks-tag-in-c-sharp/37538909#37538909)).

And, only a small thing, I changed the method name to uppercase and renamed the first parameter to `backgroundFilePath` to make it more clear it is a file and not a directory.

Comment: Why fully qualify `OpenSubKey` and nothing else?

Comment: @Peter Taylor - of course, all calls of `Registry...` should be fully qualified. I have updated the answer, added "... and all other occurances."

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well. What I mean is, what's special about `Registry`? I can see that the rule *isn't* to fully qualify anything not in a `System` namespace, because in that case you'd have mentioned `JsonConvert` as well.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

`Image` also implements `IDisposable`, therefore wrap in `using`:

```
using (Image background = downloadBackground(URL + getResolutionExtension()))
{
    saveBackground(background);
    setBackground(background, PicturePosition.Fill);
}
```

Ok, more info: `Image` may utilize a sizable amount of memory, depending on the image, so executing deterministic disposal of those resources is incumbent upon the developer in order to ensure best application behavior. Read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose) for additional information.